# How do I insert labels or annotate the points in a plot with multiple things?

Tags: point, labeling, geopandas, annotation, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a simple study area map which consists of basin boundary shapefile, sampling points and river shapefile.

Here's the dataframe of the sampling points:

[image]

And here's the code to plot the map without the labels for each sampling points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

langat_sampling_points.plot(ax = ax, color = "green", markersize = 10, zorder = 2)

langat_basin.plot(ax = ax, facecolor = "darkkhaki")

langat_river.plot(ax = ax, color = "blue", zorder = 1)

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = langat_basin.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm having difficulty trying to insert labels for each sampling points. I tried using a method from an article by Medium.

```
x = langat_sampling_points['X'].values
y = langat_sampling_points['Y'].values
station = langat_sampling_points['Stations'].values

dict1 = {}
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
n = 0

#storing the latitude and longitude values and sampling stations or points in the lists
for lon in x:
    list1.append(lon)
for lat in y:
    list2.append(lat)
for point in station:
    list3.append(point)

#storing the longitude as key and latitude as value in the dictionary    
while (n < len(list1)):
    dict1[list1[n]] = list2[n]
    n+=1
```

The part that I'm stuck is when I want to insert the label:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

langat_sampling_points.plot(ax = ax, color = "green", markersize = 10, zorder = 2)

langat_basin.plot(ax = ax, facecolor = "darkkhaki")

langat_river.plot(ax = ax, color = "blue", zorder = 1)

for lon, lat in dict1.items():
    x, y = langat_sampling_points(lon, lat)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ok', markersize = 5)
    plt.text(x, y, list3[i], fontsize = 10);
    i+=1 

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = langat_basin.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The main problem is that I don't know where to insert this code properly:

```
for lon, lat in dict1.items():
    x, y = langat_sampling_points(lon, lat)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ok', markersize = 5)
    plt.text(x, y, list3[i], fontsize = 10);
    i+=1
```

How do I solve this problem? Is there another way to solve this problem?

EDIT: Problem solved. I made a mistake for not noticing that the coordinates in X and Y columns are still in EPSG:4326 instead of ESRI:102062. Here's the code:

```
#assign the coordinates and stations in new variables
geometries = langat_sampling_points['geometry']
stations = langat_sampling_points['Stations']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 20))

langat_sampling_points.plot(ax = ax, color = "lime", markersize = 25, zorder = 2)

for station, coordinates in zip(stations, geometries):
    xy = coordinates.coords[0]
    ax.text(xy[0], xy[1], station, fontsize = 12)
       
langat_basin.plot(ax = ax, facecolor = "darkkhaki")

langat_river.plot(ax = ax, color = "dodgerblue", zorder = 1)

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = langat_basin.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are plotting markers and text at locations taken from "X" and "Y" columns of your data frame. You could do that only if your `langat_basin` data had the same type of coordinates, which is actually not the case. Try to take the coordinates directly from the "geometry":

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

# make data
data = {
    'Stations': ['SP1','SP2','SP3','SP4','SP5'],
    'X': [101.883889, 101.770556, 101.786111, 101.775833, 101.764444],
    'Y': [3.215556, 3.014444, 2.992667, 2.911944, 2.914167],
    'geometry': [Point(432181.200, 355799.208), Point(419534.783, 333589.820), Point(421258.607, 331177.849), Point(420101.013, 324465.979), Point(418832.928, 323608.771)]
}

# make geo data frame
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data)
# get geometries and station names
geometries = gdf['geometry']
stations = gdf['Stations']

# make figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot markers
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
# plot text
for s, g in zip(stations, geometries):
    xy = g.coords[0]
    ax.text(xy[0], xy[1], s)

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Alternatively, you could try to convert `langat_basin` data to your "X" and "Y" coordinates type, e.g. like this:

```py
langat_basin.to_crs(epsg='4326', inplace=True)
```

Then you can plot your markers and their annotations at (X, Y), provided that these coordinates are in the EPSG:4326 system.

In any case, you may need to check your `langat_basin` data frame like this:

```py
print(langat_basin.info())
print(langat_basin.crs)
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that the langat sampling points coordinate is still in EPSG:4326 although I set it to ESRI:102062 like langat basin & river. How do I really change the coordinates?

Comment: Sorry because I failed to notice that the coordinates of my X and Y columns are still in EPSG:4326 instead of ESRI:102062

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you for your help. Your solution is really easy to understand